# Elements with transparency not showing up against transparent background

Tags: transparency

I'm having an issue with my final output not resembling my render.
My render and what I want the image to look like is this:

[image]

But when viewed in other applications it looks like this:
[image]

I feel like I have some fundamental misunderstanding of the way transparency works in a PNG? Is there a way to fix this or is there a way around it? I want the 'aura' effect to fade into the transparent background as the image is intended to be overlayed on top of a different background.

Thanks in advance!

Blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/13iJBPP6R_dArTbBztFlpDa8Few34wvhC/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using PNG just use OPENEXR

[image]

This works.

I read about some limitations about PNG and Blender here in this forum.

> Note: be aware that if you are working on a Mac, the viewer will not
> show the EXR correctly. But if you open the exr in the image editor of
> Blender you will see it correctly. Maybe search for an exr viewer for
> mac in the internet.

further info here: [Point density and transparent background](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/128740/point-density-and-transparent-background)